# Word: Update a TableRow using the Word JavaScript Api

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I'm having difficulties to update the `values` of a `Word.TableRow` using the Javascript API. I've look to Doc and I can't find any hints that will help me to accomplish my duty...

**Here is my Question: *What is the best way to set the values of a TableRow inside a Word Document using the Javascript API.***

**And Here is what I tried:**

```
Word.run((context: Word.RequestContext) => {
    var tables = context.document.body.tables;
    tables.load("items");
    return context.sync().then(() => {
        var firstTableRows = tables.items[0].rows;
        context.load(firstTableRows, "items");
        context.sync().then(() => {
            var header = firstTableRows.items[0];
            header.load("values");
            context.sync().then(() => {
                header.values = ["MyValue"]
                context.sync();
            });
        });
    });
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

***This is a 1x2 table***

No errors are thrown and the table is not getting updated...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try removing the `.catch(errorHandler);` to see if you are generating an error.

Comment: Nop nothing is coming up

Comment: hey guys can you please share the Word build you are trying this on? seems to be an Office.js update issue (we need to ship an update to our preview API)

Comment: Here is my office.js version https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Comment: And I'm on the insider fast branch

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response here. There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. the first one is associated with a bug we are currently fixing with keeping references of items mentioned in the load method. There is a related  question on stack explaining this issue. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746951/how-to-operate-on-selected-paragraphs-from-a-javascript-addin-in-desktop-word/39755460?noredirect=1#comment66863712_39755460). (specially the detailed explanation in the comments).
2. The second issue I see with your code is that you are trying to set the row values using a 1d array, when a 2D array is expected. (and this is an error in our documentation, we need to fix it thanks to you!)

You have a couple of options for changing values, this is the first one:

```js
 Word.run(function (context) {

            var myTables = context.document.body.tables;
            context.load(myTables);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {

                var myRows = myTables.items[0].rows;
                context.load(myRows);
                return context.sync()

                .then(function () {
//assumes a table with at least 3 columns!
                   myRows.items[0].values = [["1", "3",  "4"]];
                  return context.sync()

                })
                      
            })
        })
    .catch(function (e) {
                app.showNotification(e.message);
            })
       
    }
```

Now, until the bug mentioned in the first point is fixed you need to do several trips to the host application in order to set the data you want. a potential shortcut is to use our new navigation options,specially if you want to change the first or last row values  (**please note that we are planning to rename the first to getFirst() by the time we ship the API, so this code will break in a couple of months, maybe already breaks if you are using the insider fast  release**), you can do something like this in just one call:

```js
 Word.run(function (context) {
//this gets the first row of the first table in the document and sets its values. Please note the 2D array used!
       context.document.body.tables.first.rows.first.values =[["Juan", "Peter", "Jeff"]];
            
            return context.sync()
            .catch(function (e) {
                 app.showNotification(e.message);
            })
        })
```

Please give it a try to these options and let me know how it goes.
thanks!